# Why does second use of $state.transitionTo() cause "TypeError: Cannot read property '$$nextSibling' of null"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, runtime-error, angular-ui-router

It's the strangest thing, I found the code that does exactly what I want: using ui-router to change the displayed URL without reloading the page. This is it:

```
$state.transitionTo($state.current, args, { location: true, inherit: false, notify: false});
```

The problem is, it only works the first time. After that line is called a second time, angular enters the apply/digest loop & my page breaks. The error shown in the console is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '$$nextSibling' of null
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:12569)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:12805)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:19138)
    at HTMLDivElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (jquery.js:4641)
    at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4309)
```

Comment: I should probably add that that call to `$state.transitionTo` is happening in the `$scope.watch` handler for a certain object in my model

Comment: The issue revolves around `notify: false`. Still looking into this issue myself, but using `notify: true` is a lousy albeit working solution.

Comment: Actually, turns out _toggling_ `notify` between `true` and `false` causes the issue for me. If I stick to one or the other, the problem goes away. Do you have other `transitionTo` or `go` calls that are defaulting to `notify: true`?

Answer (score 1):

The first argument for the [transitionTo()](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#methods_transitionto) function is supposed to be a String (a state name), but you are passing it an Object (the current state object).

Instead of passing `$state.current`, you should pass `$state.current.name`:

```
$state.transitionTo($state.current.name, args, { location: true, inherit: false, notify: false});
```

Without looking at the UI-Router code, I can't say if this explains the error you are receiving.

Comment: That wasn't it! It's interesting how transitionTo could recover from me passing the object though...

Comment: @LiamHession I took a look at the source code and noticed that `transitionTo()` uses a helper function called [findState()](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/src/state.js#L115) that will accept either a state name or an object. So that mystery is solved. Sorry for the misleading advice. I also checked some of my own code where I reload a state. I've seen a lot of examples/work arounds for reloading states, but I've found this simple syntax works:  `$state.go('stateName', {}, {reload: true})` Maybe that will help in your case.